# Page is not loading on selected dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, http-status-code-404

I am having this message - `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://england-cities.html` when I upload to File Zilla.

When I select a country in the first select menu, it was supposed to allow the user to choose the cities in another select menu.

The code is working perfectly fine when I use the Visual Studio Code live. but when I upload to File Zilla for some reason is not working.

As you can see in the code I am asking to load a list of data that is inside of each Html then I use the call back function to connect to Ajax weather API.

Why is this happening?

Thank you for your help.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#country').change(function () {
        $('#counties').load($(this).val() + '-cities' + '.html');
        $('#counties').change(function () {
            let stateSelected = $(this).val();
            getTheWeatherData(stateSelected);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: add your html as well to run the snippet here

Comment: full code here -  https://jsfiddle.net/lmanhaes/cq1g5dyt/25/

Answer (score 0):

Try add `'https://www.yoururl/'` after the `load()`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#country').change(function () {
        $('#counties').load('https://www.yoururl/'+$(this).val() + '-cities' + '.html');
        $('#counties').change(function () {
            let stateSelected = $(this).val();
            getTheWeatherData(stateSelected);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: didn't work either. This function was to load five HTML pages containing the data.